# Ruby generate table from date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been having a lot of trouble with this:

For an RPI application, all my results are within one table: **results**

I'm trying to print a table based on a specific data range: **2011-07-31..2012-07-01**

In my controller:

```
class SeasonsController < ApplicationController
  def s2012
  @results = Result.all
  @s2012 = Result.where(:date => (2011-07-31)..(2012-07-01))
  end
end
```

In my view:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Event ID</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
<% @s2012.each do |result| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= result.event_id %></td>
    <td><%= result.date %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

This doesn't output any errors (small miracle), but nothing is displayed in the view. `@results = Result.all` prints all the whole table just fine. But how can I limit it to a specific data range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you're trying to do this all ActiveRecordy, but imo it's actually less readable than if you just wrote the SQL where clause yourself.

```
Result.where('date BETWEEN ? AND ?',
             Date.parse('2011-07-31'),
             Date.parse('2012-07-01'))
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I feel so much better now. 

I originally tried approaching this with SQL but I couldn't get the formatting right, and it developed into an active record over the time spent trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
 Date.parse('2011-07-31')..Date.parse('2012-07-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current example rails will think you are doing arithmetic. You are looking at a date between the number 1973 and 2004. Instead you want to convert them to date objects first. Do

```
@s2012 = Result.where(:date => DateTime.parse('2011-07-31')..DateTime.parse('2012-07-01'))
```